# Javascript wrap Hebrew word and punctuation in separate span tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'm ultimately trying to take a Hebrew string in Javascript, with various punctuation, and add separate span tags to the word, and the punctuation (to make the words clickable).

For example, the string "האלה, (הופעה) {פג} פה@ גם... פה"
Should give an array that starts with something like this `["האלה", ",", "(", "הופעה".....etc]`

The point being that it takes all the actual words individually on one array, and each piece of punctuation in a separate array element, then I'm able to loop through them and add the span tag depending on what character it is. The problem is that I then need to recombine it all back into a string, but when I do a simple .join(" "), it adds a space between each piece of punctuation and each word, because it considers it all as separate words.

So how do I combine the punctuation back but connected to the original words, or accomplish this span wrapping some other way?

Here's the relevant part of my code, which works except for the spaces part :

```
var reg= /([^\u0590-\u05FF\"\']+)/g;
var nReg=new RegExp("\\w+|\\W+", "g");
var fixed=Html.split(" ").map((z, i)=>{ return z.replace(nReg, f => {if(reg.test(z)){ return "<span class=nothing>"+z.match(reg)[0]+"</span>"} else return "<span class=shtikle>"+z+"</span>"})}).join(" ");
```

With "fixed" being a variable which is appended to the document, and Html being the original string. I don't have a fiddle of it, but here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: 8]

Comment: Instead of joining with a space, how about you try putting a space before each word spans only, that after join just trim the first space character at the start of the string, then join them together with no space.